# How to plot in 1 graph in server.R with the selected input from ui.R/user

Tags: r, plot, shiny, rstudio

I would like to plot my graph depending on the input chosen by user in the checkboxGroupInput. 
For example in ui.R, I will select Item1 or Item2. When Item1 is selected, there will be 2 conditionalPanel that appear, I will then select the respective choices I need and plot it.

Currently the problem is I would all the plots to be in one plot instead of plotting additional plot.
When I check the checkbox in variable4 or variable5, there will be additional plot instead of the "stacking/overlay" effect, which I would like to change as well.

Sorry if the question is not very clear cut or confusing, please do feel free to clarify with me.

**ui.R**

```
library("shiny")

shinyUI(navbarPage(title="Title",collapsible=TRUE, inverse=TRUE,
 tabPanel("Subtitle1",
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("variable1","Items:",
                         c("Item1","Item2"))),
  mainPanel(
   plotOutput("plot1")   
   )
  )
 ),

tabPanel("Subtitle 2",
         sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
                 radioButtons(
                     inputId="Item",
                     label="Food Selection:",
                     choices=list("Item1","Item2"),
                     selected='Item1'),
                 #only show this when Item 1 is selected
                 #user choose either 1 or 2 to display to display
                 conditionalPanel(
                     condition="input.Item == 'Item1' ",
                     radioButtons(
                         "variable2",
                         "Select Either:",
                         choices=c("Quantity"="MyQuantity1",
                                   "Values"="MyValues1"),
                         selected= "Quantity")
                                ),
                 #only show this when Item 2 is selected
                 conditionalPanel(
                     condition="input.Item == 'Item2' ",
                     radioButtons(
                         "variable3",
                         "Select Either:",
                         choices=c("Quantity"="MyQuantity2",
                                   "Values"="MyValues2"),
                         selected= "Quantity)")
                                ),
                 #only show this when Item 1 is selected
                 conditionalPanel(
                     condition="input.Item == 'Item1'",
                     checkboxGroupInput(
                         "variable4",
                         "Countries:",
                         choices=names(data.frame(MyQuantity1)),
                         selected= "World.")
                                 ),
                 #only show this panel when Item 2 is selected
                 conditionalPanel(
                     condition="input.Item == 'Item2'",
                     checkboxGroupInput(
                         "variable5",
                         "Countries:",
                         choices=names(data.frame(MyQuantity2)),
                         selected= "World.")
                                 )

                            ),
            mainPanel(
                     plotOutput("plot2") 
                         ) 
                     )
         )))
```

**server.R**

```
library("shiny")
setwd("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Food_Security/R/UI & Server")
source("global.R")



shinyServer
(
function(input,output){
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        x1<-get(input$variable1)
        plot(x1)
        #x<-input$variable1
        #plot.ts(x)
})

    observe({
        if (input$Item=="Item1"){

            output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
                x2<-get(input$variable2)
                plot(x2[,input$variable4])
            })
        }

        if (input$Item=="Item2"){

            output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
                x3<-get(input$variable3)
                plot(x3[,input$variable5])
            })
        }

    })
}
)
```

Comment: The syntax for `plot(input$variable2[,input$variable3])` looks suspicious. Do you mean `plot(input$variable2[input$variable3])` (without the comma)?

Comment: @Ricky, as my dataset is a time series data, by putting input$variable2[,input$variable3] is like subsetting the data set, where it will be for example, MyQuantity1[,"World."]. Without the comma, I cannot subset it

Comment: `input$variable2` is a string, you need to grab the data by doing `get(input$variable2)`

Comment: @NicE, I can now plot Item1 graph, but Item2 cant be plot, I am not sure why, will update and edit my question. In additional I would like the plot the be in the same plot, rather than another graph as well.

Comment: @NicE I have reticfied the Item2, and it can be plot, but I am still stuck with plotting the different graph together. Thanks!